# Is there a way to implement proper links using `<a href="/">` with github pages?

Tags: html, url, github, uri, github-pages

**How can I make `<a href="/">` redirect to `https://[username].github.io/[repo]` instead of `https://[username].github.io/` with github pages?**

When serving my multi-page html website, I get a `404 - Not Found` every time I click on an `<a href="/">` link on my pages. Instead of redirecting to `https://mepley.github.io/github-pages-redirect-to-index/` where index.html is found, I am instead redirected to `https://mepley.github.io/` and thus I get the `404 - Not Found` message.

**Here is a link to a github pages site to demonstrate the issue (served from `master` branch):**
https://mepley.github.io/github-pages-redirect-to-index/

My end goal is to simply use `<a href="/">` from another html document and redirect back to index.html. **IMPORTANT: I DO NOT** want to settle for any other strategy, such as `<a href="/index.html">` or `<a href="./">` or `<a href="../">` as relative references.

The reason I'm adamant about using just `"/"` is because I'm creating a boilerplate webpack configuration for building static websites for first-time, beginning coders to deploy a simple website to github pages and I'd prefer not having to explain this idiosyncrasy to people who are just learning and are already confused to begin with.

I've tried using `<base href="https://mepley.github.io/github-pages-redirect-to-index">` tags, but this did not fix the issue. I tried other `<base>` tags as well, to no avail *(but maybe I did something wrong?)*. And as explained in my comment below I also know that relative references from the current page (i.e. `<a href="../">`) will in fact redirect to the correct homepage, but it still **DOES NOT** answer my question, unfortunately.

Here are the only two files needed to demonstrate this issue:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    This is index.html
    <a href="./another-page.html">goto another-page.html</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

another-page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    This is another-page.html
    <a href="/">go back to index.html</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expected result is that I click on the `<a href="/">` link in `another-page.html` and it redirects me back to `https://mepley.github.io/github-pages-redirect-to-index/` and finds `index.html` instead of `https://mepley.github.io/` with the 404 error as is currently happening.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Also, here is the repo link for the site: https://github.com/mepley/github-pages-redirect-to-index

Comment: The best I have been able to do is use relative references like so: `<a href="./">` or if another-page.html is nested one level deep, then  `<a href="../">`, two levels deep  `<a href="../../">` etc... The first provided answer was somewhat helpful, but did not actually answer my question. I want to simply use `<a href="/">` and it will always redirect to the homepage and serve index.html as is the typical behavior of using  `<a href="/">`. Really would appreciate if anyone has figured this out or has any ideas. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is what you did not want to do:
`<a href="/index.html"/>`. 
Please explain why you do not want to do that. It’s only 10 extra characters.

Comment: You could try putting the whole url in the link.

Comment: Okay, if you add `./` before `index.html` i.e. `<a href="./index.html">` this does work, but it still does not answer my question. I'd like to know if it is possible to use redirects with simply `<a href="/">`, because I'm building a boilerplate for creating simple, framework-less (html, css, js) websites and hosting to github pages and I would like to not have to explain that you need to explicitly use `<a href="./index.html">` for every redirect back to homepage for other people who use the boilerplate. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate any input that people have.